# GAWK Script - Print filename in BEGIN section

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, gawk

I am writing a gawk script that begins

```
#!/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN { print FILENAME }
```

I am calling the file via `./script file1.html` but the script just returns nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use ARGV[1] instead of FILENAME if you really want to use it in BEGIN block

```
awk 'BEGIN{print ARGV[1]}' file
```

Comment: That works if there is a file name - but doesn't print a dash if there isn't one (so the script is reading from standard input).

Comment: @Jonathan, the question says, "I am calling the file via ./script file1.html"

Comment: +1, but with the warning that if you use this, you can't be using any command line arguments.  So if `./script file1.html` is the only way this is going to ever be run this is fine.  If you ever add `./script --argument1ofn file1.html` you're back to being screwed.

Answer (score 11):

You can print the file name when encounter line 1:

```
FNR == 1
```

If you want to be less cryptic, easier to understand:

```
FNR == 1 {print}
```

### UPDATE

My first two solutions were incorrect. Thank you Dennis for pointing it out. His way is correct:

```
FNR == 1 {print FILENAME}
```

Comment: Either of those print the first record of the file. The correct way to use your technique for the OP's need: `FNR == 1 {print FILENAME}` (in other words, while your "less cryptic" would apply in the case of printing `$0`, it (and the variable name) are required in this case). +1 anyway

Comment: This works for multiple files while accepted answer works only for first input file. This should be accepted answer. Good job ! +1

Answer (score 7):

Straight from the man page (slightly reformatted):

> FILENAME: The  name of the current input file.  If no files are specified on the command line, the value of FILENAME is “-”.  However, FILENAME is undefined inside the BEGIN block (unless set by getline).

Answer (score 1):

Building on Hai Vu's answer I suggest that if you only want the filename printed once per file it needs to be wrapped in a conditional.

```
if(FNR == 1) { print FILENAME };
```